# Trying to make annotated citation style, getting "Error generating citations and bibliography"

Tags: citations, bibliography, csl

I have a question on some csl code.

I am trying to convert the "nature" style which is available through Zotero to an annotated style which gets the annotation by citing the "Extra" field (similar to APA 7th edition annotated).

I am not familiar with coding in csl so I found out thanks to google that all I had to do is add the line
`<text variable="note" display="block"/>`
before `</layout>`
(found this info here: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/19552/annotated-bibliography-in-mla-or-chicago-style)

I did so and now I am getting the following error when generating the style in Zotero's style editor:

> Error generating citations and bibliography:
> citeproc-js error: Level mismatch error: wanted bib_first but found bib_other

I already checked my code with the CSL style and locale editor (https://validator.citationstyles.org/) and it gives me no errors. Googling this error message does't give any good results. I am trying to use this style in Microsoft Word once it works.

Here are the last couple of lines of the code (if the line `<text variable="note" display="block"/>` is removed, then the error is gone):

```
        <text macro="editor"/>
        <text macro="volume"/>
        <text variable="page"/>
        <text macro="issuance"/>
        <text macro="access"/>
      </group>
      <text variable="note" display="block"/> 
    </layout>
  </bibliography>
</style>
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is in the specifications, but you can't mix `second-field-align` in the bibliography settings with `display` set on individual elements (because they're doing the same type of things, so the CSL processor doesn't know what you actually want to do).

I see you found a solution, but that'll not print the annotations on a new line. If you still want that, go back to

```
<text variable="note" display="block"/>
```

But then remove the `second-field-align` from bibliography, i.e. for *Nature*, turn it into

```
<bibliography et-al-min="6" et-al-use-first="1"  entry-spacing="0" line-spacing="2">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That indeed fixed the problem. However, the period at the end of the citation is now in a new line (meaning I now have three lines instead of two). Is there any way to prevent this, or, to keep the period between citation and annotation?

Comment: I think if you remove the `suffix="."` from `<layout>` that might be enough. 
You could then add it to the group that goes from the beginning to right before the note variable and/or you could add it to the line with `<text variable="note"` depending on how you need punctuation to look

Comment: That did the trick! I added `suffix=". "` to certain spots within <layout> </layout> where I thought they would be good to have (<text macro="issuance" suffix=". "/>
        <text macro="access" suffix=". "/>). Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was now able to fix this by replacing the line I added with

`<text variable="note" prefix=""/>`

There is no error message anymore and the citations look great! I will leave this question up, in case anyone is or will be struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think the problem is that you only used `display="block"` on a single element under `<layout/>`. Per https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/1.0.1/specification.html#display, "The display attribute ... may be used to structure individual bibliographic entries into one or more text blocks. **If used, all rendering elements should be under the control of a display attribute.**"

If you want the annotations to appear on a new line, I'd try introducing a new `<group display="block">...</group>` that encompasses the original content of `<layout/>` in the bibliography section, followed by `<text variable="note" display="block"/>`.

Comment: This isn't actually a problem -- e.g. the APA annotated style on the CSL repository has display set on only one element and works fine. Especially with `display="block"` that's also often the only way to get the desired behavior. This is in practice; you're right about the specifications, of course, and we should likely revisit that bit.